What are the famous recorded Chinese political speeches?
What are the famous political speeches in recent Chinese history that were (A) in Chinese, and (B) have audio recordings available for them?
Current list:

Mao's 'the PRC is now founded' speech
Zhao Ziyang's Tianamen square speech
Zhou Enlai's statement during negotiations with Nixon

As an additional question, what are the most famous speeches for each of the Chinese leaders? (e.g Xi Jinping's most famous speech, etc, etc)

Not sure if this is considered as a political speech but it’s very famous. (This question is a little off-topic.)

Jiang Zemin's speech in 1998 great flood.


the famous political speeches in Chinese history

the chinese culture emphasise on written texts; that, in narrow sense, it’s a no
in boarder sense, there’re several famous political articles, such as:
前出師表
正氣歌
復多爾袞書

I think he meant political speeches in modern China (from 1911) or new China (from 1949).  But your answer is "so correct":)

@r13 , well, the op mentioned “chinese history”

From his citation, it appears that, in his view, Chinese history is only about a hundred years old :) Hope he will come back to edit the question to be more specific.

Sorry, by 'recordings' I meant 'audio' recordings, hence the examples from recent history ...

Search 学习强国, you might get some of the speeches of the current boss.
